# List Box Should be Drop down

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

to every one
I have some values in my data base i Want to display them with check boxes.
those values should be display when i click at the button. This should not in combo box.
because I want to post multiple values at one time.
Please help with thanks

```
<?php

$womenlist=mysql_query("select * from tbl_cycleduraion where user_id=$_SESSION[user_id]");
$gs=0;
while($girlslist=mysql_fetch_array($womenlist))
{
    $gs++;
?>
<li style="background-color:#CCC; width:150px;"><label for="chk1"><input type="checkbox" name="chk_<?php echo $gs?>" id="chk<?php echo $gs?>"  value="<?php echo $girlslist['calName'];?>" <?php if($_REQUEST['chk_'.$gs]==$girlslist['calName']){?> checked="checked"<?php }?>><?php echo $girlslist['calName']." ".$girlslist['calDesc']; ?>  </label></li>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Thanks for response sir . From this make a list box with all values. Actually I want to display these values by clicking. these values should be like drop down

Answer (score 0):

You could limit the number of columns in your query (not `SELECT * ...`). You've put the `<input>` inside the `<label>`. The `<label>`'s `for=""` attribute is hardcoded as `chk1`. You could take out the inline `style=""` on the `<li>` and put it into a stylesheet. I've "tidied" it up a bit (untested):

```
$womenlist = mysql_query("select * from tbl_cycleduraion where user_id=$_SESSION[user_id]");
$gs = 0;
while( $girlslist = mysql_fetch_array($womenlist) )
{
$gs++;
echo '<li style="background-color:#CCC; width:150px;">'
   . '<label for="chk' . $gs . '">' . $girlslist['calName'] . ' ' . $girlslist['calDesc'] . '</label>'
   . '<input type="checkbox" name="chk_' . $gs . '" id="chk' . $gs . '" value="' . $girlslist['calName'] . '"
   . (($_REQUEST['chk_'.$gs]==$girlslist['calName']) ? 'checked="checked"' : '') . '></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure entirely what you're asking for here (as it looks like you already have this working with checkboxes), but you can in fact post multiple values with a select box. You just use the `multiple` attribute, and specify the name as an array with the square brackets:

```
<form action="yourscript.php" method="post">
  <select name="women[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="woman1_name">Woman 1</option>
    <option value="woman2_name">Woman 2</option>
    <option value="woman3_name">Woman 3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

If you post a form with this, selecting woman 2 & 3, `var_dump($_POST);` yields:

```
array(1) {
  ["women"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "woman2_name"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "woman3_name"
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want the values of your checkboxes to come through in a similar fashion, change them so they all have the same `name`, but with the square brackets on the end. This HTML would yield similar POST data:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="women[]" value="Woman 1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="women[]" value="Woman 2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="women[]" value="Woman 3" />
```

So, to create a dropdown using this, here's an adaptation of your code. I believe this is what you're after:

```
<?php
$options = '';
$womenlist=mysql_query("select * from tbl_cycleduraion where user_id=$_SESSION[user_id]");
while($woman=mysql_fetch_array($womenlist)) {
    $options .= '<option value="'.$woman['calName'].'"'.((!empty($_REQUEST) && in_array($woman['calName'],$_REQUEST['women'])) ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$woman['calName'].' '.$woman['calDesc'].'</option>';
}
?>
<label for="women">Women:</label>
<select id="women" name="women[]" multiple="multiple">
    <?php echo $options; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for response sir . From this make a list box with all values. Actually I want to display these values by clicking. these values should be like drop down.

Comment: Have edited in code to generate a select box with the appropriate HTML.

Comment: Thanks again but result same.Sir i want like this
http://www.andytimney.com/projects/jquerydropdown/

Comment: It would have been much more useful to post this link in your original question.If you're looking to mimic that exactly, just use your PHP to render the same HTML markup and lift the JS. That page is essentially the answer to your question - just view source.